# `module-not-found` while expose a component with NextJs module federation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webpack-module-federation

Keep getting `- error Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Test'`
Here is what my `next.config.js` looks like

```js
const NextFederationPlugin = require('@module-federation/nextjs-mf');

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: 'next-js',
          remotes: {},
          filename: 'static/chunks/remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './test': './components/Test',
          },
          shared: {
            react: {
              requiredVersion: false,
              singleton: true,
            },
          },
        }),
      );
    }
    return config;
  },
  // your original next.config.js export
  reactStrictMode: true,
};
```

Here is my file structure

```
src
  -- app
  -- components
       -- Test.tsx
next.config.js
```

Did I miss anything?

Tried to expose a component from next js with module federation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use complete path of file with extension in expose object.
Replace

```
exposes: {
            './test': './components/Test',
          },
```

with

```
exposes: {
            './test': './components/Test.tsx',
          },
```